# Class Keyword - Explicitly Indicating Inherited Interfaces?

Tags: c#, class, interface, sqldatareader

[SqlDataReader's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) class statement includes IDataReader, IDataRecord and IDisposable even though these are all implemented by its base class, [DbDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class SqlDataReader : DbDataReader, 
  IDataReader, IDisposable, IDataRecord {...}

public abstract class DbDataReader : MarshalByRefObject, 
  IDataReader, IDisposable, IDataRecord, IEnumerable {...}
```

In this case, is there some technical advantage to indicating that the derived class implements interfaces which its base class already indicates that it implements? (I can't think of one. Wondering if this is a legacy relic, a typo or something done for documentation purposes.)

Comment: Where you saw this? Can't see this on the [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs) site.

Comment: @Dmitry, well `IDataReader` is defined in both, but the answer is no, there's no reason to add redundant interface declarations.

Comment: @KirkWoll What about explicit interface implementation? There is one in the `SqlDataReader` class: `IDataReader IDataRecord.GetData(int i)`.

Comment: @Dmitry, ah, good catch. So it's not redundant after all.

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitry! I missed that. That makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done in order to add or override explicit interface implementations in the derived class. For example,

```
interface IFoo
{
    string P {get;}
}

class Base: IFoo
{
    string IFoo.P 
    {
        get { return "Base"; }
    }
}

class Derived: Base, IFoo
{
    string IFoo.P 
    {
        get { return "Derived"; }
    }
}
```

If `Derived` doesn't implement `IFoo` directly, it cannot define an explicit implementation of `IFoo.P`, so it cannot override the implementation in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense if you want to implement some interface explicitly.
For example:

```
interface ISome
{
    void Method();
}

class A : ISome
{
    public void Method()
    {
    }
}

class B : A, ISome // Try to remove ISome...
{
    void ISome.Method()
    {
    }
}
```

If you comment out the `ISome` in the `B` declaration, compilation will fail.